# how to create backup for update tables structures in existing DB?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have Sql Server DB, I know I can Create thru **"Generate Scripts"** backup for **SP** and **Functions** then I just replace inside the script the **"CREATE"** with **"ALTER"**, that will update the target DB with the latest Functions And SP **but how to do that for Tables structures  and "User Defined Tables" ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of synchronizing the schema between two databases is not a simple one.  In general, you will need to either write change scripts manually using `ALTER TABLE` commands or use specifically designed software which will generate the `ALTER` statements for you.

Either way, any error can cause loss of data on a massive scale if you select the wrong column to delete, or make your `varchar(30)` into a `varchar(3)` column.

I can recommend you take a look at [RedGate's SQLCompare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/), [Visual Studio Ultimate or Premium](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) - which is free.  All three will take two databases, backups or scripts and generate the DDL needed to move from one to the other.

Comment: Thanks alot ...exactly what I have looking for. I have used SQL Server Data Tools.

Answer (score 3):

Another tool, apart from those already mentioned is [ApexSQL Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx)

As Mitch has already mentioned, writing update scripts that will synchronize two databases manually is quite a risky job. You can maybe try to compare by creating scripts for all objects and then use a file compare tool to find the deltas between the two schemas and change it. But for even a bit larger databases I would not recommend this method since it’s quite easy to miss some change

For some object types you can use query like this that will give you objects that are not equal but note that this doesn't cover everything.

```
select O.name, sm1.definition
from DB1.sys.sql_modules AS sm1
inner join DB2.sys.sql_modules as sm2 on sm1.object_id = sm2.object_id
inner join DB1.sys.all_objects O on sm1.object_id = O.object_id
where sm2.definition <> sm1.definition
```

*Disclaimer: I'm working for ApexSQL as a Technical Support Engineer*